# Problemas al referenciar un boton del menu despegable HTML

Tags: html, jquery, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Me encuentro con el siguiente problema, estoy creando un menu desplegable en HTML y hasta al momento casi todo funciona correctamente. El problema viene cuando quiero seleccionar el apartado "servicio industrial" dentro del despegable "servicios" para que me redireccione a otro documento html no lo hace, simplemente se cierra el despegable de "servicio".

Puse dentro del atributo href la dirección del documento a abrir y no lo hace, sin embargo, si esa misma dirección la pongo en los apartados como lo son "contacto o "inicio" que no son despegables si me redirecciona pero solo en los despegables que son "servicio industrial", "servicio automotriz" y "redes sociales" no lo hace

La parte interactiva la hago en jquery. Adjunto los codigos.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu li:has(ul)').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).hasClass('activado')){
            $(this).removeClass('activado');
            $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('.menu li ul').slideUp();
            $('.menu li').removeClass('activado');
            $(this).addClass('activado');
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
        }

    });

    $('.btn-menu').click(function(){
        $('.navbar .menu').slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(document).width() > 450) {
            $('.navbar .menu').css({'display' : 'block'});
        }

        if ($(document).width() < 450) {
            $('.navbar .menu').css({'display' : 'none'});
            $('.menu li ul').slideUp();
            $('.menu li').removeClass('activado');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:  border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
        background: #fff;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        line-height: 18px;
}

a {
    text-align: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #272727;
}

.btn-menu {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #0d2c44;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-menu .icono {
    float: right;
}

.navbar {
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.navbar .menu {
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar .menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: #f20200;
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #f20200;
}

.navbar .menu .icono {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.navbar .menu .icono.izquierda {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.navbar .menu .icono.derecha {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.navbar .menu ul {
    display: none;
}

.navbar .menu ul li a {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar .menu .activado > a {
    background: #1a95d5;
    color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 80px;
    }

    .navbar {
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .btn-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar .menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    user-sacalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title> Caure comercializadora</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="btn-menu">Menu<i class="icono fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i>Servicios<i class="icono derecha fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="servicio_ind.html"><i class="icono izquierda fa fa-industry" aria-hidden="true"></i>Servicios Industriales</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicio_aut.html"><i class="icono izquierda fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i> Servicios Automotrices</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contacto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>Redes Sociales<i class="icono derecha fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js">          </script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta cambiar

```
$('.menu li:has(ul)').click(function(e)
```

por una clase especifica y no por el elemento. ej:

```
$('.desplegable').click(function(e)
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li class="desplegable">
```

Tienes un conflicto de etiquetas y debes separarlas de alguna manera.
Atento a tu respuesta.

Comment: La solución fue: En el Jquery cambie el metodo de evento "e.PreventDefault();" por "e.stopPropagation();" de esa forma se pudo solucionar.